# How to write current network speed

Tags: networking, bash

I need to write my current network speed into a file.

An example is:

```
the_command_you_suggest --number-of-iterations 4 --interval 5 --interface eth0 > output.txt
```

This is the `the_command_you_suggest`, and it runs 4 times for example and each iteration waits 5 seconds.

How can I do this? I see other commands which give me my current network speed but I cannot write them. They're mostly only real-time and cannot be saved.

Comment: You will need to use a CLI extension, such as this https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli, the use native bash to iterate with a delay. Note, that this site isn't a script-writing service.

Comment: @spikey_richie I don't want to download to measure my speed. I want to see if my network is currently being used and how much it is using.

Comment: So what are you testing the speed between? Your NIC and the gateway?

Comment: @spikey_richie no, I just want to know my current bandwidth speed. For example, I want to see if currently my server is downloading/uploading a file and see its result, but I want to send the output to a file to save that. I don't want to test and measure my bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Install nload and parse (grep + sed + awk , etc) its output and write it your log file.

For reference, read this article: https://www.tecmint.com/nload-monitor-linux-network-traffic-bandwidth-usage/

Comment: In its current form, this is a comment, not an [answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). Please use correct markdown when writing answer/questions - please see the formatting bar or the help icon on the formatting bar